# How can I extract two separate matrices from a file?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

So I have a file that looks something like this:

```
# 3  # Number of network ROIs
# 2  # Number of netcc matrices
# WITH_ROI_LABELS
    001             002              003
      1               2                3
# CC
  1.0000          0.9800          0.9895
  0.9800          1.0000          0.9817
  0.9895          0.9817          1.0000
# FZ
  4.0000          2.2965          2.6240
  2.2965          4.0000          2.3426
  2.6240          2.3426          4.0000
```

- I want to extract the 3x3 matrix labelled "CC"
- I want to extract the 3x3 matrix labelled "FZ"

So I did the following:

```
file=/users/3dfile1
A= numpy.genfromtxt(file)
m= A[:,:]
m
```

So the output I get looks like this:

```
array([[ 1.    ,  2.    ,  3.    ],
       [ 1.    ,  2.    ,  3.    ],
       [ 1.    ,  0.98  ,  0.9895],
       [ 0.98  ,  1.    ,  0.9817],
       [ 0.9895,  0.9817,  1.    ],
       [ 4.    ,  2.2965,  2.624 ],
       [ 2.2965,  4.    ,  2.3426],
       [ 2.624 ,  2.3426,  4.    ]])
```

However, my question is... if I have multiple files. Where the matrix size is NOT CONSISTENT.  This means that in some files the matrix will be 3x3, some files 8x8, 1x1, etc. In this case, how can I code something that will:

- differentiate the matrix CC from FZ
- extract the matrix (can detect the size of matrix somehow and give me the exact matrix I'm looking for)

Comment: What have you tried up to now? Why is this tagged "Java"? Doesn't "Number of network ROIs" give the dimension of the matrix?

Comment: @daniu not sure, I thought I could do this somehow using java. Although python seems like the way to go.  Also, yes you're right. The number of network ROI's does give the dimension of the matrix.  But numpy.genfromtxt doesn't detect the commented text.

Comment: I'm still not clear on the problem.  Are you asking how to read in multiple files?

Comment: Yes I want to read them in basically.  The reason I'm doing this is because I want to do a computational step afterwards, but it requires me to read it first. @DemetriP

Comment: Ok, I think I understand what is going on.  You have one file, and in that file are many matrices.  Looks like you will have to reshape the data.  Currently trying something

Comment: Yes, exactly that's what it is @DemetriP

Comment: I've added an answer.  If it does what you need, please accept it.

Comment: That looks great, thank you and I will accept the answer. but I had one question. When you do reshape step: `x2 = x1.reshape(2,3,3)` that is specific to this file, is there a way that we can replace the 3,3 with some variable that represents the size of the matrix? Because as I mentioned in my question, I would like this code to work for different sized matrix (without me manually entering it everytime).  Is there a way that we can take the number of ROI's listed at the top to be the matrix size which we will place in the code x1.reshape(2,x,x)? @DemetriP

Comment: Yea, you could just assign a variable to the number of colums.  Something like `len_roi = x1.shape[1]` `x1.reshape(2,len_roi,len_roi)`.

Comment: @DemetriP much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `genfromtxt` accepts input from anything that gives it a list or iterable of lines.  So you could run your file through a filter function that splits it into blocks, and call `genfromtxt` for each block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[ 1.    ,  2.    ,  3.    ],
       [ 1.    ,  2.    ,  3.    ],
       [ 1.    ,  0.98  ,  0.9895],
       [ 0.98  ,  1.    ,  0.9817],
       [ 0.9895,  0.9817,  1.    ],
       [ 4.    ,  2.2965,  2.624 ],
       [ 2.2965,  4.    ,  2.3426],
       [ 2.624 ,  2.3426,  4.    ]])

x1 = x[2:,:]

x2 = x1.reshape(2,3,3)

CC ,FZ = x2
```

Result:

```
In [23]: CC
Out[23]: 
array([[ 1.    ,  0.98  ,  0.9895],
       [ 0.98  ,  1.    ,  0.9817],
       [ 0.9895,  0.9817,  1.    ]])

In [24]: FZ
Out[24]: 
array([[ 4.    ,  2.2965,  2.624 ],
       [ 2.2965,  4.    ,  2.3426],
       [ 2.624 ,  2.3426,  4.    ]])
```

Comment: I have a question, I'm not sure if you'd be able to answer.  If I wanted to take this one step further and write a for loop to get all the average values of the array from multiple files how could I do that? So I want the CC of each file to be averaged with the CC array of another file, and so on so forth. 
I'm only asking you because you'd probably understand what I'm looking for the most since you helped me with the first part of the question.  I could also post that as a separate question if you're able to help me and I will rate your answer :)  @Demetri P

Comment: We're going beyond the scope of this particular question.  I'll point you to numpy's documentation for tips on calculating means of ndarrays.  IF after searching you still need help, feel free to make another post.